# Zimbra: autoprov - unable to authenticate zimbratest@domain.ru for auto provisioning

Tags: ubuntu, email, zimbra

Подскажите, кто сталкивался. Уже неделю пытаюсь настроить AutoProv на Zimbra, раньше работало(настраивали до меня), потом перестало.

Zimbra ver. 8.0.4_GA_5737.FOSS

```
zimbra@mx:~$ zmprov gd domainru | grep AutoProv
zimbraAutoProvAccountNameMap: sAMAccountName
zimbraAutoProvAttrMap: sn=displayName
zimbraAutoProvAuthMech: LDAP
zimbraAutoProvBatchSize: 20
zimbraAutoProvLdapAdminBindDn: synczimbra@domainru
zimbraAutoProvLdapAdminBindPassword: passwd
zimbraAutoProvLdapBindDn: %u@%d
zimbraAutoProvLdapSearchBase: OU=group,DC=office,DC=sushishop,DC=ru
zimbraAutoProvLdapSearchFilter: (&(sAMAccountName=%u)(mail=*@domainru ))
zimbraAutoProvLdapURL: ldap://192.168.5.254:389
zimbraAutoProvMode: LAZY
zimbraAutoProvNotificationBody: Добрый день! Вы получили Ваше первое письмо на свой корпоративный почтовый ящик ${ACCOUNT_ADDRESS} Рекомендуем Вам сохранить данное письмо. Пройдите по следующей ссылке sharepoint.domainru /For ALL/Instruction.docx
zimbraAutoProvNotificationFromAddress: synczimbra@domainru 
zimbraAutoProvNotificationSubject: New account auto provisioned
zimbra@mx:~$
```

Logs:

```
zimbra@mx:~$ tail –f /opt/zimbra/log/mailbox.log | grep zimbratest@domainru 
2015–05–26 12:37:07,297 INFO [qtp964346941–487:127.0.0.1:80/service/soap/AuthRequest] [oip=192.168.157.157;ua=zclient/8.0.4_GA_5737;] account — unable to auto provisioing acct zimbratest@domainru 
2015–05–26 12:37:07,298 INFO [qtp964346941–487:127.0.0.1:80/service/soap/AuthRequest] [oip=192.168.157.157;ua=zclient/8.0.4_GA_5737;] SoapEngine — handler exception: authentication failed for [zimbratest@domainru ], account not found
```